# Bash script special character and background job bug

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "
sh -c '
 gedit'/media/ubuntuman/Onces And for Al/scripts/faceBook' & ;
 sudo cpulimit -e ubuntu-tweak -l 80;'"
```

This is the piece of code I want to edit. The special character `'` (single quote) in  of `sh -c` will conflict with the single quote of `gedit`, how can I solve it?

I also find that if I run the first job in the background, the terminal doesn't execute the second job of `sudo cpulimit` bla bla ... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following command, it should start both jobs:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "
sh -c '
 (gedit /media/ubuntuman/Onces\ And\ for\ Al/scripts/faceBook &) ;
 sudo cpulimit -e ubuntu-tweak -l 80;'"
```

Parentheses denote a subshell in bash. To quote the man page:

```
   (list) list is executed in a subshell environment (see  COMMAND  EXECU‐
          TION  ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin com‐
          mands that affect the  shell's  environment  do  not  remain  in
          effect  after  the  command completes.  The return status is the
          exit status of list.
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein when something fails, please explain _how_. Just saying "It doesn't work" is not very useful.

Comment: sorry for that :)
it works as a syntax but as logic it opens in gedit facebook once and plain new documents he doesn't consider it absolute path

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein: I must admit that I didn't really understand the purpose of such launcher but actually I'm able to have the gnome terminal, gedit and a third job started this way without the issue of gedit closing the last process. Indeed some detailed feedback would help

Comment: `gnome-terminal --tab -e "
sh -c '
 (gedit '/media/ubuntuman/Onces\ And\ for\ Al/scripts/faceBook' &) ;
 sudo cpulimit -e ubuntu-tweak -l 80;'"`

`(gedit '/media/ubuntuman/Onces\ And\ for\ Al/scripts/faceBook' &)` must open the file named in the absolute path , Right ? 
this doesn't  happen what happen is Gedit open separated new documents named Onces,And,for,faceBook, scripts

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein I've updated my answer so that you can get the right doc opned by gedit now, give it a try

Comment: wonderful u just eliminate those couple signle quotes from within the parentheses , right  ?

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein Indeed, much simpler this way. As it would require crazy escape sequences as this command mix sh with other subcommands.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using any special (i.e., special for the shell) characters in the filename, and since you're not giving any further commands, you can use the `-x` option and leave out the surrounding quotes for the shell:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -x bash -c \
   'gedit "/media/ubuntuman/Onces And for Al/scripts/faceBook" & \
    sudo cpulimit -e ubuntu-tweak -l 80'
```

Note that an `&` need not be followed by a `;`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion ,but can u please suggest me something for the same commands --tab -e sh-c

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein 1. You don't need to use `sh`. `bash` will work fine. If you insist on using `sh`, then just replace `bash` with `sh` in my command. 2. The `-x` option replaces `-e`.

Comment: the point is after this command  

`gnome-terminal --tab -x bash -c \
   'gedit "/media/ubuntuman/Onces And for Al/scripts/faceBook" & \
    sudo cpulimit -e ubuntu-tweak -l 80'` i add more sets of lines like other `--tap -e` so the surrounding quotes can be left for the shell in that case too ?

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein and why are you doing this? I can see the point behind running `sudo cpulimit ...`, but why do you have to run `gedit` from inside the terminal? Where are you going to use this?

Comment: it is a script to run some tasks once it is executed :) can we fix this ?

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein  So do this: `gedit "/media/ubuntuman/Onces And for Al/scripts/faceBook" & gnome-terminal --tab -e 'sudo cpulimit -e ...' --tab -e 'some other command ...'`

Comment: there is no way to escape those two single quotes of gedit within the script so the compiler doesn't consider them as a end of sh-c ??

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein you can escape anything you want with \: `-e 'sh -c  "gedit \'/media/ubuntuman/Onces And for Al/scripts/faceBook\' & sudo cpulimit -e ubuntu-tweak -l 80"'`. But the more complex your command, the more annoying escaping becomes. It's easier and simpler to split out commands.

Comment: this is what i get when i use \ for escaping
`Failed to parse arguments: Argument to "--command/-e" is not a valid command: Text ended before matching quote was found for '. (The text was ' sh -c ' gedit \'/media/ubuntuman/Onces And for Al/scripts/faceBook\' &; ' ')`

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein :D Good. Now you understand why escaping correctly is a pain. I'm not going to go crazy looking for the correct set of escapes here, and neither should you.